# Django admin model plural mode global settings, not adding suffix 's'

Tags: python, django, model, pluralize, plural

We're now using Django.

And our Language is Chinese.

While you know, In Chinese grammar, the plural case is usually the same as the single case. At least, not just adding an English letter 's' after the word.

So, Since we've set the `verbose_name` of every Model classes as Chinese, and found that in the admin panel, all Models are displays as XXs.

Now we have to set the plural manually, just the same as the `verbose_name` itself:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'the_table_name'
    verbose_name = 'object_name'
    verbose_name_plural = 'object_name'
```

So, is there any way to set the global plural transform rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying 'verbose_name_plural' is the simple way to override the meta option in django models. But if you want to set it programatically, then you  can do this by defining your own meta class like this:

```
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

class CustomModelMetaClass(ModelBase):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        klas = super(CustomModelMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        klas._meta.verbose_name_plural = klas._meta.verbose_name

        return klas
```

Now use this meta class in your models like this

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    __metaclass__ = CustomModelMetaClass
```

It will set the verbose_name_plural same as verbose_name. To validate this open shell, import model Poll and print

```
unicode(Poll._meta.verbose_name_plural)
unicode(Poll._meta.verbose_name)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but just as you said, This is not the efficient way to improve my code.

Comment: It has no problem related to efficiency.   I just want to say that you should use metaclasses causiously. Also if its working fine, please accept the answer.